# Issue with appending text area to a particular comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a HTML code to be able to reply to comments. The issue I'm having in the code below is when I click the reply button it appends the reply text area to both comment 1 and comment 2. What can I do to make it only append the text area to only the relevant comment.

```
<script>
    function reply2comment() {

    $("div#reply").html('<form action="" method="GET" id="rati"><textarea style="border-radius:0em" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="maximum 100 characters" maxlength="100" rows="4" cols="60" required></textarea>'+ 
        '<div class="save_reply"><input type="submit" data-theme="e" id="send_reply" value="save"/></div></form>').trigger('create');
        }

</script>
```

```
<div class="userReviews">
<div class="userDP_mP"><img src="display_pics/yy.jpg" alt=""/></div>
<a href="#" data-ajax="false"><div class="userName_mP">Tim</div></a>

    <img style="max-width:95%" class="reviewRateImage" src="ratingPlanets/hot_earth.png" alt=""/>

    <div class="review_mP"><p>comment 1</p></div>
</div>
<!-------------------------------->
<div class="reply">
<input type="button" data-theme="e" onClick="reply2comment()" value="reply"/>
</div>
<!----reply text area----->
<div style="width:80%; margin-left:15%;" id="reply"></div>


<div class="userReviews">
<div class="userDP_mP"><img src="display_pics/xx.jpg" alt=""/></div>
<a href="#" data-ajax="false"><div class="userName_mP">David</div></a>

    <img style="max-width:95%" class="reviewRateImage" src="ratingPlanets/hot_earth.png" alt=""/>

    <div class="review_mP"><p>comment 2</p></div>
 </div>
<!-------------------------------->
<div class="reply">
<input type="button" data-theme="e" onClick="reply2comment()" value="reply"/>
</div>
<!----reply text area----->
<div style="width:80%; margin-left:15%;" id="reply"></div>
```

Comment: It's doing exactly what you asked for, changing the HTML of the `div` with `id = "reply"`.  The issue is that you have two divs that use the same ID, which is invalid HTML.  Fix your HTML, problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks Tibrogargan, I have changed the ID to a class but I'm still getting the same result :(

Comment: Do you mean that you changed your selector (`$("div#reply")` to (`$("div.reply")`) or that you added a class to each textarea container `div` and also changed your selector to use the new class?  Might be an idea to update your question with the new code

Comment: I changed the ID to a class ("reply9") and also changed the selector $('div.reply9').

Comment: You changed it to a class, but they still both have the same class, no?  Of course it's changing both.  You need to give them different IDs or different classes or figure out some other way to select them.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 divs with the same id "reply". This makes your `$("div#reply").html(...` command append it to the both of them.

1. IDs should be unique. You shouldn't have more than 1 element with the same ID attribute.
2. If a jQuery selector matches more than one element, it will call the `html(` methon on both of them.

Comment: Thanks Ixe, I have changed the ID to a class but I'm still getting the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is what something you could do.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".reply").bind("click",
    function reply2comment(event) {
      var $replyContainer = $(event.currentTarget).siblings("#reply");
      $replyContainer.html('<form action="" method="GET" id="rati"><textarea style="border-radius:0em" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="maximum 100 characters" maxlength="100" rows="4" cols="60" required></textarea>' +
        '<div class="save_reply"><input type="submit" data-theme="e" id="send_reply" value="save"/></div></form>').trigger('create');

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="userReviews">
  <div class="userDP_mP">
    <img src="display_pics/yy.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <a href="#" data-ajax="false">
    <div class="userName_mP">Tim</div>
  </a>

  <img style="max-width:95%" class="reviewRateImage" src="ratingPlanets/hot_earth.png" alt="" />

  <div class="review_mP">
    <p>comment 1</p>
  </div>

  <!-------------------------------->
  <div class="reply">
    <input type="button" data-theme="e" value="reply" />
  </div>
  <!----reply text area----->
  <div style="width:80%; margin-left:15%;" id="reply"></div>
</div>

<div class="userReviews">
  <div class="userDP_mP">
    <img src="display_pics/xx.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <a href="#" data-ajax="false">
    <div class="userName_mP">David</div>
  </a>

  <img style="max-width:95%" class="reviewRateImage" src="ratingPlanets/hot_earth.png" alt="" />

  <div class="review_mP">
    <p>comment 2</p>
  </div>

  <!-------------------------------->
  <div class="reply">
    <input type="button" data-theme="e" value="reply" />
  </div>
  <!----reply text area----->
  <div style="width:80%; margin-left:15%;" id="reply"></div>
</div>
```

I modified you user_reviews markup to group the reply div and the reviews together.

And changed the event handlers from markup to script, just to make it easier to bind events.

Comment: Hi Sreekanth, this is still giving me the same result.

Comment: I see reply section is being appended to only one comment section. isnt that what you are looking for? reply only have one text area when clicked on button.